# I've tried to give a physicsBodyComponet to modelEntity, and It just falls deep down

Tags: arkit, realitykit

On reality kit, I've tried to give a physicsBodyComponent to a modelEntity.

But as I put to modelEntity to real world, It just fall down.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: Exactly same issue here... I'm trying to get my entities to not be able to overlap each other, and as far as I understood, this would be achieved with a physicsBodyComponent, but everything then falls down due to gravity...

Comment: I kind of featured out. You have to make a plane modelEntity & give it a physicsbody. 1 exception is that if you run on ipad pro 2020, it's done automatically.

Comment: I've tried that, but my models keep falling through it. Would you mind sharing some of your code (for creating the plane, or even also what PhysicsBodyComponent you gave to your "normal" Entities)? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I managed to make my entities stand on the plane, the key seemed to be to set a non-zero mass to the PhysicsBodyComponent of my Entities: `PhysicsBodyComponent(shapes: collisionComponent.shapes, mass: 1, material: nil, mode: .dynamic)`.
Thanks again for the pointer!

Comment: Oh, did you make it work ? with not having plane physicsBody ? Could you share how you did it?

Comment: I just added my answer below :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a floor mesh with a `PhysicsBodyComponent`:

```swift
let floor = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: [1000, 0, 1000]), materials: [SimpleMaterial()])
floor.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
if let collisionComponent = floor.components[CollisionComponent] as? CollisionComponent {
    floor.components[PhysicsBodyComponent] = PhysicsBodyComponent(shapes: collisionComponent.shapes, mass: 0, material: nil, mode: .static)
    floor.components[ModelComponent] = nil // make the floor invisible
}
scene?.addChild(floor)
```

Then, when you load your entities, you also give them a `PhysicsBodyComponent` (and they need a non-zero `mass`, otherwise they will anyways fall through, which is what eluded me for a long time):

```swift
var loadModelCancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
loadModelCancellable = Entity.loadModelAsync(named: modelUri)
  .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in
      loadModelCancellable?.cancel()
  }, receiveValue: { entity in
      entity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)

      if let collisionComponent = entity.components[CollisionComponent] as? CollisionComponent {
          entity.components[PhysicsBodyComponent] = PhysicsBodyComponent(shapes: collisionComponent.shapes, mass: 1, material: nil, mode: .dynamic)
      }

      scene.addChild(entity)
      loadModelCancellable?.cancel()
  })
```

In the end, adding physics to my project had too many unintended consequences for what I was trying to do (just preventing models to overlap), like models pushing each other, and movements needing to be redone completely, ... So I didn't get further than this, but at least this should let you add physics to your models without them falling indefinitely from gravity.